# Matching values from different objects in the same array with angularJs

Tags: angularjs, json, object

I have this json below, if there where more objects with more countries and and medals, what would would be the best approach in angular to match medals won to specific countries?

```
[
{
"athlete": "KOGO, Micah",
 "country": "KEN",
 "sex": "Men",
"event": "10000m",
"medal": "Bronze"
},
{
"athlete": "BEKELE, Kenenisa",
"country": "ETH",
"sex": "Men",
"event": "10000m",
"medal": "Gold"
},
{
"athlete": "SIHINE, Sileshi",
"country": "ETH",
"sex": "Men",
"event": "10000m",
"medal": "Silver"
},
{
"athlete": "FLANAGAN, Shalane",
"country": "USA",
"sex": "Women",
"event": "10000m",
"medal": "Bronze"
 }
]
```

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: display a medal count for each country and what medals won

Comment: Okay, and how would you like that output structured? I was thinking you might be able to provide a sample output based on the sample input.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, do you mean like a liike a unordered list?

Comment: There's a certain assumption that your input above will be put through some kind of function to process the data and produce an output. The many 1000s of users on the site are willing to provide the function, if you can provide the expected output.

Comment: An unordered list would be a form of output yes, show us what you want. Is order of the countries important? Is the colour of the medals important? Do you want a count of each colour? Do you just want a list of all colours won?

Comment: Yes They are all important factors, what I wanna do is try understand the process that is needed to make that happen. How do I loop through the array and assign the medals to each individual country? Do I take out the vales out of the object and add it to an a new object? I'm not sure where to even start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates an unordered list of countries with counts of the medals.

```js
var app = angular.module("yourApp", []);

app.controller("controller", function($scope) {

  $scope.input = [{
      "athlete": "KOGO, Micah",
      "country": "KEN",
      "sex": "Men",
      "event": "10000m",
      "medal": "Bronze"
    },
    {
      "athlete": "BEKELE, Kenenisa",
      "country": "ETH",
      "sex": "Men",
      "event": "10000m",
      "medal": "Gold"
    },
    {
      "athlete": "SIHINE, Sileshi",
      "country": "ETH",
      "sex": "Men",
      "event": "10000m",
      "medal": "Silver"
    },
    {
      "athlete": "FLANAGAN, Shalane",
      "country": "USA",
      "sex": "Women",
      "event": "10000m",
      "medal": "Bronze"
    }
  ];

  $scope.countries = $scope.input.map(function(obj) {
    return obj.country;
  });

  $scope.uniqueCountries = $scope.countries.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return $scope.countries.indexOf(item) == pos;
  })

  $scope.getMedalCount = function(country, colour) {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.input, function(obj) {
      if ((obj.country === country) && (obj.medal === colour)) {
        count++;
      }
    });
    return count;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="yourApp">
  <div ng-controller="controller">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="country in uniqueCountries">
        {{ country }}
        <ul>
          <li>Gold: {{ getMedalCount(country, "Gold") }}</li>
          <li>Silver: {{ getMedalCount(country, "Silver") }}</li>
          <li>Bronze: {{ getMedalCount(country, "Bronze") }}</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```